# change H3 value on clicking but the value appear

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to replace the value of H3 with p value when select on of them.
But when clicking the H3 content replaced with p but P disappear.

```js
    $(".selec li p").on("click", function() {
     var singleValues =  $( this );
      $(".years h3").html(singleValues);
      console.log(this);

    });
```

```html
<div class="years">
   <h3>Year</h3>
   <p>Publications for</p>
   <ul class='selec'>
    <li class="show"><p href='#'>2011</p></li>
    <li><p href='#'>2012</p></li>
    <li><p href='#'>2013</p></li>
    <li><p href='#'>2014</p></li>
    <li><p href='#'>2015</p></li>
    <li><p href='#'>2016</p></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are giving `html()` a dom element, so it's going to move it.  If you want to set the text, you can just give it the innerHTML.

```js
$(".selec li p").on("click", function() {
     var singleValues =  $( this );
      $(".years h3").html(this.innerHTML);
      console.log(this);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="years">
   <h3>Year</h3>
   <p>Publications for</p>
   <ul class='selec'>
    <li class="show"><p href='#'>2011</p></li>
    <li><p href='#'>2012</p></li>
    <li><p href='#'>2013</p></li>
    <li><p href='#'>2014</p></li>
    <li><p href='#'>2015</p></li>
    <li><p href='#'>2016</p></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```